# Running Same Regression Across Multiple Individuals

Tags: r, regression, logarithm

I am trying to run a log log regression of the form LNX ~ LNP, where X = Units Sold and P = Price (in reality, I would have a number of other variables included in the model).  The data is retail data; ultimately, I want to run the exact same regression above for each individual item.  so, LNX ~ LNP for Item # 1, LNX ~ LNP for Item #2, and so forth.

I have tried a number of methods, but for each method, the intercept and coefficient are coming out the same for all items (ie, intercept for item # 1 = intercept for item # 2 and so on).  This is clearly incorrect and is an artifact of my being a novice to R.

Below is a toy data set that is similar in nature to a real data set I'm working with.

[image]

Below is one of the codes that I've tried.

```
T<-read.csv("ElasticityToy.csv")
X = log(T$Units)
P = log (T$Price)
model<-lapply(1:2, function (i) lm(formula = X ~ P, data = T))
```

This, again, gives the exact same intercept and coefficient for each both item # 1 and item # 2.  There is the added difficulty that this is panel data, so any input here is appreciated as well.

Ultimately, I'm looking to elasticity for each item (impossible given the simple form I've presented here, I know, but I'm looking more for code help at this point as I'm new to R).

I appreciate any help you can give.  Mods, if this is the incorrect place to post this, can you please point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this is a programming question and does not belong to our page. But since it is related to the concept of *interactions*, maybe we can still help you here.

#### Approach 1: Correct your code

```
myT <- read.csv("ElasticityToy.csv")
model <- lapply(1:2, function (i) lm(log(Units) ~ log(Price), data = subset(myT, Item == i)))
```

The problem is twofold

1. The function your were applying to each element of the list did not depend on $i$
2. You have a data argument in `lm' without using its column names in the formula.

Also it is helpful to not overwrite "official" names like "T" (short for "TRUE") by your own objects.

#### Approach 2: Use interactions

To get individual elasticities (but maybe same coefficients for all other variables than price), you can also use a price/Item-interaction, i.e. estimating a separate price slope for each level of interaction (which must be a factor here). In fact, you will get the intercept and slope for your first item, and additionally, the change in intercept and slope for each other item.

So you can write something like

```
model <- lm(log(Units) ~ log(Price)*factor(Item), data = myT)
```

When you compare the models (without further variables), you will get the same predictions, but with the advantage of only having one model and e.g. one R-squared etc.

Comment: Thank you. This worked.  I appreciate you answering the question, even though it was posted on the incorrect page.  Is there a place where I should be posting programming related questions?  Thanks again for your help.  I tried voting your answer up, but I do not yet have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: This would be the site for programming problems: `http://stackoverflow.com` ;-)